# How does backtracking in recursion not cause an infinite loop?

Tags: prolog

Assume the member/2 predicate is defined as:

```
member(X,[X|R]).
member(X,[Y|R]) :- member(X,R).
```

My query is:

```
member(X, [1, 2, 3]).
```

Once prolog unifies X with 1, how does prolog get the other possible unifications if I type `;`?
Wouldn't Prolog backtrack and then re-read my file containing the definition of member from top to bottom and evaluate `member(X,[X|R]).` again which would unify X with 1 again?

Answer (score 1):

The rules you stated are:

1. `member(X, [X | R]).`

The pipe operator separates the first element of the list from the rest of the list. So, if list is `[1, 2, 3]`, `X = 1`, and `R = [2, 3]`.
`X` is the `car` of the `[X | R]` list (i.e. first member).

So in this case, `member(1, [1, 2, 3]).` is `true`.

2. `member(X, [Y | R]) :- member(X, R).`

This second case covers when the first member of the list is different from X. If this is so, `member(X , R)` is called and this inspects the `cdr` of the list (i.e. from second element on).

So, `member(1, [1, 2, 3]).` doesn't trigger a recursion.

---

What happens, for instance, when the element is not on the list ?

For brevity, `member(1, [2]).` is `true` or `false` ?

This falls on the second rule, since `X = 1` is different from `Y = 2`.

But then, the `cdr` of the list is an empty list (i.e. there are no elements beside the first).

So `member(1, [2]) :- member(1, []).`, and this `member(1, [])` evaluation is always `false.`

---

Prolog's output:

```
~ $ swipl
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [user].
|: member(X, [X | L]) :- write('Evaluated first clause with X='), write(X), write('.'), nl.
|: member(X, [Y | L]) :- write('Evaluated second clause with X='), write(X), write(' and Y='), write(Y), write('.'), nl, member(X, L).
|: end_of_file.
% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- member(1, [1, 2, 3]).
Evaluated first clause with X=1.
true .

?- member(2, [1, 2, 3]).
Evaluated second clause with X=2 and Y=1.
Evaluated first clause with X=2.
true .

?- member(4, [1, 2, 3]).
Evaluated second clause with X=4 and Y=1.
Evaluated second clause with X=4 and Y=2.
Evaluated second clause with X=4 and Y=3.
false.

?- X=1, member(X, [1, 2, 3]).
Evaluated first clause with X=1.
X = 1 .
```

(omitted warnings).

Comment: "This second case covers when the first member of the list is different from X" - no, that's not true. It doesn't care about unifying the first element. The second case simply ignores the first element to enable it to recursively call the predicate on the remainder of the list.

Comment: It is true. You can test on swi-prolog. The chained rule is. The second rule alone is not sufficient.

Comment: I also feel that calling the cdr `null` is wrong too. Prolog either unifies or it doesn't, so `[X]` does not unify with `[_|Y]` as prolog expects `Y` to be a non-empty list.

Comment: It's not true. It does not cover the case when the first element is different from `X`. It doesn't care what the value of `X` is at all.

Comment: What do you call an empty list ? I lacked a better name.

Comment: No, sorry, my mistake. It does unify with the empty list. It's not `null` though. It's an empty list.

Comment: The statement "This second case covers when the first member of the list is different from X" is still wrong.

Comment: It's not. The `Y` symbol represent some value different than `X`. It's the second clause of the "production".

Comment: No, it doesn't care if it is different or not. There's nothing in the clause that determines inequality. It just ignores the value and moves on.

Comment: Take a look at the output of evaluations in edited answer. The first clause takes care that the first member of the list is the same symbol that the queried item. Since there are 2 clauses, when the first fails, the next one has Y different than X.

Comment: Not if Prolog is backtracking - and it does that a lot.

Comment: Instead of using ^D (Ctrl-D) you should use `end_of_file.` ([ref](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/UndefinedCode.html))

Answer (score 1):

How about this

[image: member/2 execution]

Note the following:

- The program is read once and then stays in memory, waiting for the user to enter a query (same as for a database scenario)
- As it executes it builds a "search tree" in memory

  - An OR node for every predicate encountered: ANY of the branches (which correspond to clauses of that predicate) must be made TRUE
  - An AND node for every clause body encountered: all the branches (which correspond to the calls made in the clause body that are seprated by `,`) must be made TRUE
- The program SUCCEEDS when it can "exit at the bottom of the tree" and

  - Below any AND node, all the branches are TRUE
  - Below any OR node, at least one of the branches are TRUE (In Prolog, there is only every exactly ONE "active branch" below an OR node)
- The program eventually FAILS if no such tree can be found (which may take some time).
- On program success, the tree is kept alive in case the user ask for "more solutions"
- If you ask for "more solutions", the tree is re-entered at the bottom and alternative branches are tried.

And:

- Variable names are **local to a clause**
- Variable content (which is either a term or a cell with no content if the "variable is unbound" as they say) is **always global**. If a node deep in the tree "refines" the content of one of its variable, this change is visible at the topmost node of the tree (albeit under another name or part of another term).